# How to obtain other Entities in C# WebCore Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a C# WebCore REST service that talks to a front end and uses Entity Framework to CRUD into a database. This uses Dependency Injection to add the contexts upon startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<FileCacheContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Settings.ConnectionSetting));
services.AddDbContext<FileImportContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Settings.ConnectionSetting));
```

The functionality that I have allows a user to upload a file, which is manipulated by the server and some properties of that file are returned to the front end. The uploaded file is cached in the database (FileCacheContext).

After some time has passed, the user now wishes to confirm their action and "promote" the file from the Cache (FileCacheContext) to the Import (FileImportContext); this is done by an action in the front end that contains the id of the cached file.

This parameter is passed to a different REST Controller, which is being invoked using the FileImport context, rather than the FileCache context:

```
public PromoteController(FileImportContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] int fileCacheId)
{
...
```

What I now need to do is to "move" this cached file from one "context" to another, something along the lines of:

```
var cachedFile = _context.FileCache.Where(f => f.FileCacheId == cachedFileId).FirstOrSingle();
var importedFile = new FileImport() { FileData = cachedFile.FileData };
_context.FileImport.Add(importedFile);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

My issue is that I can only see the one context, so I cannot get hold of the other context to either read from or write into.

The two underlying tables have no relationship, so I cannot link them in any way to load one based upon the other.

How can I get access to another (unrelated) context in EF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question, I found that I could of course include the additional contexts required when instantiating the controller:

```
public PromoteController(FileImportContext contextImport, FileCacheContext contextCache)
{
    _contextImport = contextImport;
    _contextCache = contextCache;
}
```

And then use these as required.

This doesn't *feel* like the right way to do it, but if it works, it works...